# Estou tentando tirar o box-shadow do meu accordion-item, mas não consigo

Tags: html, css

```css
.col-flex {
  display: inline-block;
}

.accordion-item {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.button1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  color: var(--primary);
}

.button-bol {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #84C226;
}

.button-bol:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #84c226;
  color: #808191;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #84c226;
}

.button-bol:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #84c226;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #84c226;
}
```

```html
<div class="pb-3 text-center" id="myGroup">
  <h2 class="text-center fs-2" id="titulo">Boletim Informativo</h2>
  <hr style="width: 30%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 1.5rem">
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn1 button1 button-bol col-5" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse8" role="button" area-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExemple"><b>Agosto - 2021</b></button>
    <button class="btn btn2 button1 button-bol col-5" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse7" area-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExemple"><b>Julho - 2021</b></button>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <div id="collapse8" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="col-flex accordion-body">
            <img src="img/botetimA1.jpeg" alt="Boletim-1 Agosto" width="48%" style="float: left; margin-bottom: 2rem">
            <img src="img/botetimA2.jpeg" alt="Boletim-2 Agosto" width="48%" style="float: right; margin-bottom: 2rem">
            <img src="img/botetimA1.jpeg" alt="Boletim-1 Agosto" width="48%" style="float: left;">
            <img src="img/botetimA2.jpeg" alt="Boletim-2 Agosto" width="48%" style="float: right;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image: Print do meu codigo]

```
Eu quero tirar essa linha que esta abaixo dos buttons. a linha fica assim quando os buttons não esta ativo
```

[image: Print com as imagens dentro do collapse]

> Nessa imagem da pra ver as imagens dentro do button collapse. Não estou conseguindo anexar as fotos para ver melhor no codigo

Comment: no HTML que você partilhou não aparece essa linha. Não consegue postar mais codigo e imagens que funcionem para vermos melhor?

Comment: vou tentar postar ele todo

Comment: sou nova nesse site, e estou apanhando tentando colocar o codigo com as imagens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A linha cinza abaixo dos botões está na div que tem a classe "accordion-item", você pode escondê-la sobrescrevendo esta regra css:

```
.accordion-item {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

Lembrando que essa regra css vai sobrescrever todos os elementos que tiverem esta classe, o ideal seria definir uma classe em alguma div mais acima deste item, neste caso ficaria algo assim:

```
<div class="accordion-modificado">
  <div class="accordion-item">
  ...
  </div>
</div>

.accordion-modificado .accordion-item {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou Diego, muito obrigada.